# How to call an Objective-C method from a AudioUnits C function? (iOS)

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I found a great tutorial on AudioUnits (http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) that I've since got working on my system; however, I'm having trouble calling my Objective-C methods from the RenderTone C function.

In the same m-file as RenderTone, I have the following method:

```
- (Float32)signalGenerator:(int)sample withSampleRate:(int)Fs andFrequency:(float)frequency{
```

When I try and call this method from the RenderTone function, XCode gives me the following error:  "Use of undeclared identifier 'signalGenerator'."  Why can't it see this method if it's in the same file?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Apple recommends not sending Objective C messages inside Audio Unit callbacks.  Best to stick with plain C function calls instead.

Comment: @hotpaw2 OK, thanks, good to know.  (I'm looking to have the sound change based on the user's interaction with the UI.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `RenderTone()` function,

```
ToneGeneratorViewController *viewController = (ToneGeneratorViewController *)inRefCon;
```

is the instance of your view controller, so you can call your method

```
Float32 x = [viewController signalGenerator:13 withSampleRate:14 andFrequency:15];
```

from within `RenderTone()`. To make the method known to the compiler at that point,
you can either

- move `RenderTone()` inside the `@implementation ToneGeneratorViewController` block, or
- add a function prototype using a class extension:

  ```
  @interface ToneGeneratorViewController ()
  - (Float32)signalGenerator:(int)sample withSampleRate:(int)Fs andFrequency:(float)frequency;
  @end
  ```